# What is the best way to retrieve data with dates from the last month in Mendix and compare them using XPath?

Tags: mendix

I'm new to mendix and I ran into a problem comparing dates in mendix.

My task is to collect data whose date is one to the date of the last month.

e.g. date>=01.04.2023 && date<=30.04.2023

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EaSb.png)

What is the easiest way to select the beginning of the last month and the end of the last month.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to be using the `beginOfMonth` function, depending on what you want (question is not 100% clear to me), in combination with `addMonths`.

See also [here](https://docs.mendix.com/refguide/begin-of-date-function-calls/) and [here](https://docs.mendix.com/refguide/add-date-function-calls/)